# Python complete newbie, JSON formatting

Tags: python, json

I have never used Python before but am trying to use it due to some restrictions in another (proprietary) language, to retrieve some values from a web service and return them in json format to a home automation processor. The relevant section of code below returns :

```
[u'Name:London', u'Mode:Auto', u'Name:Ling', u'Mode:Away']
["Name:London", "Mode:Auto", "Name:Ling", "Mode:Away"]
```

…which isn't valid json. I am sure this is a really dumb question but I have searched here and haven't found an answer that helps me. Apologies if I missed something obvious but can anyone tell me what I need to do to ensure the json.dumps command outputs data in the correct format?

```
CresData = []
for i in range(0, j):
    r = requests.get('http://xxxxxx.com/WebAPI/emea/api/v1/location/installationInfo?userId=%s&includeTemperatureControlSystems=True' % UserID, headers=headers)

    CresData.append("Name:" + r.json()[i]['locationInfo']['name'])

    r = requests.get('http://xxxxxx.com/WebAPI/emea/api/v1/location/%s/status?includeTemperatureControlSystems=True' % r.json()[i]['locationInfo']['locationId'], headers = headers)

    CresData.append('Mode:' + r.json()['gateways'][0]['temperatureControlSystems'][0]['systemModeStatus']['mode'])

Cres_json = json.dumps(CresData)
print CresData
print Cres_json
```

Comment: The first output, with the `u''`s, is from `print CresData` and is the Python-native list data structure. The second output is from `print Cres_json` and is valid JSON. Soooo… don't `print CresData`…!?

Comment: Try this : Cres_json = json.dumps(json.loads(CresData))

Comment: @Shekhar `CresData` is a `list`, you cannot `json.loads` that.

Comment: @WayTooUnCool Could you tell what is your expected output format?

Comment: yes @deceze i see that now , It makes no sense to use json.dumps() either

Comment: @saurabhbaid 1. You're addressing the wrong person, 2. what's the purpose of such a comment? It's just noise.

Comment: @Shekhar Sure it makes sense to use `json.dumps` if you want to produce JSON data…

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test the code as the link you mentioned is not a live link but your solution should be something like this

It looks like you are looking for JSON format with key value pair. you need to pass a dict object into json.dumps() which will return you string in required JSON format.

```
CresData = dict()
key_str = "Location"
idx = 0
for i in range(0, j):
    data = dict()
    r = requests.get('http://xxxxxx.com/WebAPI/emea/api/v1/location/installationInfo?userId=%s&includeTemperatureControlSystems=True' % UserID, headers=headers)
        data["Name"] = r.json()[i]['locationInfo']['name']
    r = requests.get('http://xxxxxx.com/WebAPI/emea/api/v1/location/%s/status?includeTemperatureControlSystems=True' % r.json()[i]['locationInfo']['locationId'], headers = headers)
        data["mode"] = r.json()['gateways'][0]['temperatureControlSystems'][0]['systemModeStatus']['mode']
    CresData[key_str + str(idx)] = data
    idx +=1

Cres_json = json.dumps(CresData)
print CresData
print Cres_json
```

Comment: JSON has *objects*, which are like `dict`s, yes, but JSON also has *arrays*, which are like `list`s. There's absolutely no requirement to pass `dict`s to `json.dumps`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's most helpful and the output looks a lot better. I should, however, have been a little more specific in terms of what I am looking to achieve. Ultimately, I would like something like this :

Comment: {
"Location1": [
            {
              "mode": "Auto",
               "temperature": 20.5,
               "isAvailable": true
              }]
“Location2” [
{
              "mode": "Auto",
              "temperature": 20.5,
              "isAvailable": true
             }]

Comment: I need to learn how to use this site, the Enter button keeps posting my messages! I was trying to start "simple" with just location and mode, but ultimately the location is the top level, with the various attributes at the next level. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: I have upated the answer, you can build your key dynamically like above, Bear with me for any syntax errors

Comment: @deceze Though I was wrong on saying that JSON is restricted to dict like structure but apparently that was the format WayTooUncool was looking for.
I have edited my answer to remove that statement that it JSON requires dict like objects

Comment: Not the down voter. But two things here: first, why have you added another counter `idx` when `i` already exists? Second, it doesn't  produce the requested structure. `data` should be in a list (no idea why)

Comment: Definetly we can use `i` for indexing I just oversighted it and if you need to put it into list it would be just `CresData[key_str + str(idx)] = [data]` but somehow it did not make sense to me so deliberately kept that one out.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is most helpful and informative. I very much appreciate the help.